# Issue the ticket from sabre API

Tags: php, sabre

We have successfully implemented the sabre low fare search and book workflows and created the PNR . Now , I want to issue the ticket of that PNR using api.

My **workflow** is :

```
1. BargainFinderMaxRQ (find)
2. EnhancedAirBook (book)
3. PassengerDetails (create PNR)
```

My **workflow to issue ticket** :

```
1. TravelItineraryReadRQ(Retrieve PNR).
2. DesignatePrinterLLS (Print tickets)
3. AirTicketLLS (Issue tickets)
```

Now , I get the error while implementing the `DesignatePrinterLLS`.

**Request XML**

```
<DesignatePrinterRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ReturnHostCommand="false" TimeStamp="2016-04-30T05:38:20+00:00" Version="2.0.1">
 <Printers>
     <BagTag LNIATA="XXXXX9" />
 </Printers>
</DesignatePrinterRQ>
```

**Response**

```
<DesignatePrinterRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.0.1">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
                <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2016-04-30T02:45:29-05:00">
                    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <stl:Message>INVALID ENTRY</stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
        </DesignatePrinterRS>
```

What child element should we provide in `<Printers>` element. If my workflow to get the ticket is wrong then how can I get the ticket from sabre ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Change AAA (if you have another pseudo city code)**

**2. DesignatePrinterLLS (Print tickets)**

**2.1 Ticket**

```
<DesignatePrinterRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0.1">
          <Printers>
            <Ticket CountryCode="IN" LNIATA=""/>
          </Printers>
    </DesignatePrinterRQ>
```

**2.2 Hardcopy**

```
<DesignatePrinterRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0.1">
          <Printers>
            <Hardcopy LNIATA="XXXXXXXX"/>
          </Printers>
    </DesignatePrinterRQ>
```

**3. TravelItineraryReadRQ**

**4. AirTicketLLS (Issue tickets)**

Answer (score 3):

Bagtag printer only applies If you are building a solution for an airline (not travel agency).
To expand on CSE 52 answer, I am assuming you reviewed this?
https://github.com/sabredevstudio/sabreapisworkflows

It provide instruccions on issue air ticket workflow too.