# Issue the ticket from sabre API for existing PNR Issue

Tags: xml, web-services, sabre

I want to Issue tickets for existing PNR. I followed all the steps showed in workflow https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/workflows/Issue_Air_Ticket. In the last step it show error

```
<stl:Message>ASSIGN HARDCOPY PRINTER FOR ETR DOCUMENTS-USE PTR/-0052</stl:Message>
                    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>  





<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
          <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10</eb:PartyId>
          </eb:From>
          <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">malikexpress.com</eb:PartyId>
          </eb:To>
          <eb:CPAId>DF08</eb:CPAId>
          <eb:ConversationId>SWS-Test-Tool-CID</eb:ConversationId>
          <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">Air Shopping Service</eb:Service>
          <eb:Action>AirTicketLLSRS</eb:Action>
          <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>e2625944-efad-41a9-9aef-a2b5cead5af5@61</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2016-05-24T11:26:00</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>mid:20001209-136453-2333@clientofsabre.com</eb:RefToMessageId>
          </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
          <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-34018177098454633901!1586251!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
      </soap-env:Header>
      <soap-env:Body>
        <AirTicketRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.7.0">
          <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2016-05-24T06:26:00-05:00">
              <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                <stl:HostCommand LNIATA="61DB8A">WÂ¥PQ1Â¥ETRÂ¥FCAÂ¥KP0.00</stl:HostCommand>
                <stl:Message>ASSIGN HARDCOPY PRINTER FOR ETR DOCUMENTS-USE PTR/-0052</stl:Message>
                <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
              </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
          </stl:ApplicationResults>
        </AirTicketRS>
      </soap-env:Body>
    </soap-env:Envelope>
```

How we can remove this error? are we need a printer that showed be connected to the system?? Similar kind of question is already asked in [Issue the ticket from sabre API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952949/issue-the-ticket-from-sabre-api/36963433#36963433)

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like the ticket printer has been created appropriately.

Things I would check.

1) When you create the session have you designated a ticket printer to the session using the DesignatePrinterLLSRQ API before attempting to issue the ticket and is this being successful?

2) Is one of the ticket issue qualifiers your using or does this ticket itself require a paper ticket rather an electronic ticket.

At a guess this error may pop up when you are trying to issue a paper ticket against an assigned electronic ticket printer.

Comment: i was using wrong printer address like  LNIATA="22DC8A".  The agent told me allotted Printer address. and then its worked... :) 
thanks for your anwser..